# One router with Multiple components in Angular

Tags: angular

I have two components which are DashboardComponent and LoginComponent. when user hits my website url i.e http://localhost:4200
I have to render LoginComponent if user hasn't logedIn already. If user has logged in already, I have to render Dashboard component in the same route i.e http://localhost:4200

`this.router.navigate(['login']);`

Using this will require another route (/login). But I have to switch the components based on the logged in condition in the same route just as like facebook,instagram. how to achieve this in angular?

**Update**
This is my router config

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: DashboardComponent}
];
```

Comment: Can you update question with your route config?

Comment: use canActivate Guard feature of router it checks whether user login token is available then allows to dashboard [Reference](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3)

Comment: I understood canActive Guard. But i would like to switch the components with the same routing

Comment: @Chenna, updated the router config. Currently it will redirect to Dashboard. canActive Guard service will check if user has loged in already or not. But both components has to route to http://localhost:4200

Answer (score 1):

Somehow i have found the work around. But im not sure if it is correct approach!

in DashboardComponent.html

```
<app-login *ngIf="!loginService.isUserLoggedIn()"></app-login>
<p *ngIf="loginService.isUserLoggedIn()">dashboard works!
        <button (click)="loginService.logOut()" class="btn btn-danger">logout</button>
</p>
```

Created LoginService

```
export class LoginService {

  constructor() { }

  public authenticate(username, password) {
    if (username === "abishek" && password === "password") {
      sessionStorage.setItem('username', username)
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem('username')
    return !(user === null)
  }

  public logOut() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('username')
  }
}
```

In LoginComponent.ts while click on login button which call `checkLogin()` function

```
checkLogin() {
    if (this.loginservice.authenticate(this.username, this.password)
    ) {
      this.router.navigate([''])
    } else
      // some error
  }
```

My routing config remains same